# Publishing - most read/visited print and online media for .NET?

Tags: .net, documentation, publish

In the job of a technology evangelist, it is essential to reach as many developers and architects as possible with blogs, articles, demos, videos, etc. to introduce new frameworks and products.

Which media (print and online), platforms, etc. would you consider as essential in the .NET Community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd point to these ones:

- CodeProject.
- WROX Press books .
- O'Reilly books.
- MSDN Magazine.
- www.ayende.com
- MSDN Channel 9.
- ASP.NET - official web (blogs).